# OpenGL custom viewing routine flight simulator

Tags: opengl, 3d

One of the ways to view a scene is to either use gluLookAt or to create your own custom viewing routine. I came across this custom viewing routine in a flight simulator in a book.

```
void pilotView(GLdouble planex, GLdouble planey,
GLdouble planez, GLdouble roll,
GLdouble pitch, GLdouble heading)
{
    glRotated(roll, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glRotated(pitch, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glRotated(heading, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glTranslated(-planex, -planey, -planez);
}
```

Rotating the camera by x degrees clockwise is equivalent to rotating the target object by x degrees counterclockwise. Thus, when we specify the "roll" angle for example, shouldn't we be writing "glRotated(-roll, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)" instead of "glRotated(roll, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)"?

Answer (score 0):

No, we should not, in OpenGL triangles are transformed not camera OpenGL does not have notion of camera; so when you add a rotation to the transform your object will be rotated by this updated transform.

gluLookAt just sets up transformation of the objects as if you are looking at it, but still what is transformed is the object.

As for this function my guess is that it sets transformation to set it so that view would be aligned with plane instead of being aligned with horizontal and hang in the center instead of behind that is why we have + sign on rotations and - sign on translations. Note that calls do not set transformation, but update it.

Comment: Exactly. That is my question. The "camera" is just a way to visualize a viewing operation. What my question is that if the airplane is to be rotated about its z axis by an angle "roll", then shouldn't the glRotate call be glRotated(-roll, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)? That is what we did for the glTranslate call. We wrote glTranslated(-planex, -planey, -planez) instead of glTranslated(planex, planey, planez) which is because, we are moving the objects away from the eye coordinates by an amount specified by planex, planey and planez.

Comment: @user1903168 updated answer, but to be more precise you should provide details on how coordinate system is set up in your simulator.